# Does TLG own BrickLink?

Tags: lego-group, bricklink

At the bottom of Bricklink.com appears the following statement:

> 3. LEGO® is a trademark of the LEGO Group of companies which does not sponsor, authorize, or endorse this site.

However, according to [this press release from 2019](https://www.lego.com/aboutus/news/2019/november/lego-bricklink) TLG is in the process of acquiring Bricklink.

Has this acquisition gone through? Is the Lego Group the owner of Bricklink? What does this mean for Bricklink and for independent marketplaces in general?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, TLG has acquired Bricklink. There have been multiple news, FAQ's and interviews posted with regards to a future of the website. You can read some of them on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/r3/announcement/lego_bl_faq.page) as well as [LEGO](https://lan.lego.com/news/overview/the-lego-group-acquires-bricklink/) webpages. You can also [read an interview](https://www.brothers-brick.com/2019/11/26/news-the-lego-group-acquires-bricklink-from-nexon-founder-jay-kim-for-undisclosed-sum-interview-with-lego-cmo-julia-goldin/) with LEGO representative.

The footer on BL's webpage has been left as it was prior to acquisition. Perhaps there wasn't time to change it yet.

Comment: My last BrickLink seller bill came from “LEGO BrickLink, Inc”